# mouseevent for jquery for selection on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the color when my mouse click on the specific row on table and it should not change the color when mouse leave from that row. Please gothrough my coding and you will understand.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
    });
    $("tr").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });
    $("tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">

  <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid1">
      <td>1</td>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid2">
      <td>2</td>
    <td>karthi</td>
    <td>svks</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid3">
      <td>3</td>
    <td>raj</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid4">
      <td>4</td>
    <td>raja</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid5">
      <td>5</td>
    <td>kumar</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid6">
      <td>6</td>
    <td>kali</td>
    <td>mdu</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid7">
      <td>7</td>
    <td>madu</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid8">
      <td>8</td>
    <td>kalai</td>
    <td>mdu</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

According to the above code, if we enter the mouse into a table row, it changes to the **lightgray** color. After that, when we leave that row, it changes to **white** color. Then, when we click on a specific row, it changes to **yellow** color, when we leave from that it also changed to **white** color.

My need is, if I click on the row of a table, it should set **yellow** color and it should not change to **white** when leaving.

Please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not a correct aprroach. You shouldn't change inline styling of every item - that's why people have invented CSS.

Describe the CSS rules for `tr` and for a custom class like `selected`. Then, just add `selected` class to `tr` on click.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").on("click", function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

```css
tr:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

tr {
    background-color: white; 
}

tr.selected, tr.selected:hover, tr.selected:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>karthi</td>
    <td>svks</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>raj</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid4">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>raja</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, you can easily manipulate with colors, `hover` effects etc. 
For example, if you want to disable this "yellow-selecting" on clicking again and add an effect to selected `tr` on hover - you can change it in a moment by editing a single line of code. Check this example out (click on a row twice):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
});
```

```css
tr:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

tr {
    background-color: white; 
}

tr.selected, tr.selected:hover, tr.selected:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>karthi</td>
    <td>svks</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>raj</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid4">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>raja</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Arun_Indian Why isn't? Do you mean that it is not working or do you mean that you are not allowed to use CSS?

Comment: Sorry sir, its my mistake.. Now its perfectly working for me... Also I accept your answer too.... Didnt you notice that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mix of css and jQuery as given below.

To set the mouseover style, use :hover rule, but exclude the clicked elements are given below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });

});
```

```css
tr:not(.clicked):hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

tr.clicked{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">

  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>karthi</td>
    <td>svks</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>raj</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid4">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>raja</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid5">
    <td>5</td>
    <td>kumar</td>
    <td>vnr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid6">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>kali</td>
    <td>mdu</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid7">
    <td>7</td>
    <td>madu</td>
    <td>ttl</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="trid8">
    <td>8</td>
    <td>kalai</td>
    <td>mdu</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS No Use Jquery

```
table tr:hover{backgound:red;}
table tr:focus{backgound:yellow;}
```

Comment: But my task is, it should be in jquery